# sql server creation of logins and users by another user

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server Express 2005. 
I have a single database myDB

I have created a Login L-1 with user U-1 on databas myDB.

To connect to database myDB I found 3 ways:

-1(a)-after creating L-1 Login with default database = myDB , I have to create a user U-1 , and when I connected to SQL server , then it connected.

I used this query:

```
create login L-1 with password='passL1'  , default_database = myDB

use myDB

create user U-1 for login L-1
```

Means, creating a user inside a login , gives the user connect permission implicitly. Am I right ?

-1(b)-I didn't create any user U-1, but executed this :

```
use myDB

sp_grantdbaccess L-1
```

this also made me connect , the reason being that, sql added a user named L-1 implicitly in the myDB database. Am I right?

-1(c)-this time also, I didn't create any user U-1,but I executed this:

```
sp_changedbowner L-1
```

this also made me connect , the reason being that, sql added a user named L-1 implicitly in the myDB database. Am I right?

Now, I want to give the user U-1 created in 1(a) the following permissions:

1. Create Logins L-2,L-3
2. Create Users U2,U3 which can also connect to database myDB.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - calling `sp_grantdbaccess` or `sp_changedbowner` will just implicitly do what you would normally do with `CREATE USER` - no difference.

Calling `CREATE USER` explicitly is just **clearer**, more obvious what you're doing etc.

Also: don't use `sp_grantdbaccess` anymore - because:

> *This feature **will be removed** in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use CREATE USER instead.*

Source: [Technet on sp_Grantdbaccess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178013.aspx)

And don't use sp_changedbowner either - same reason:

> *This feature **will be removed** in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use ALTER AUTHORIZATION
>   instead.*

Source: [Technet on sp_changedbower](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx)

Comment: @sqlchild: the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) most of the time very clearly lists what permissions are required. Use MSDN!! It will tell you: to create logins, you must have the `ALTER ANY LOGINS` permission - to create or update users, you need `ALTER ANY USERS`